# Confirm browser back button else stay on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript or jquery I need to add an alert when the user clicks on the browser back button that has an ok/cancel button model, but instead of "Ok" it should say Leave and instead of Cancel it should say Stay. Thanks

Comment: See [
How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own).  The bottom line is that the only flexibility for this dialog is adding a string.  This is for security reasons.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't control the confirmation dialog button text, it's a hard coded feature of [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.confirm) and is whatever the browser has...not much you can do about it.

For the actual display you can use `window.onbeforeunload`, but it won't be specific to the back button, any action leaving the page will trigger this, for example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you wish to leave this delightful page?";
}
```

Comment: I don't think `window.confirm` really has anything to do with it.  It's just that both the `confirm` and `onbeforeunload` dialog boxes happen (in most browsers) to have OK and Cancel, and the underlying GUI code may be similar.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to try to call `confirm` in your `onbeforeunload`?  Standard practise is to just return the string, and let the browser do the prompting.

Comment: @Matthew - Sorry if I was unclear...my point was whatever the buttons are, you can't change that "Ok" or "Cancel" or whatever the browser has...which seems to be what the OP is after.

Comment: Do you know how to do it without the custom button labels?

Comment: @RichieHindle - That works as well, the prompt was just an example, my point was more that the OP may want to rethink the approach, since you can't narrow it to *only* the back button, nor can you change the prompt button text.

Comment: @sway - The example in the question, or as Richie alluded to, `return "Are you sure you wish to leave this delightful page?";` also works, but it won't be back button specific, e.g. you'll want to unbind it when going to a place that you *don't* want to prompt, on form submission, etc.

Comment: I don't think `confirm` does work.  In Firefox at least, you can execute confirm in the `onbeforeunload` handler, but I don't think you can block the page change based on a `confirm` result in any browser.

Comment: Ok so I did the window.onbeforeunload and in Chrome got this dialog, so I guess it's a chrome thing. http://cl.ly/265934776cc780ed873d

Comment: @Matthew - Ah didn't realize FireFox prevented that, updated with a simple return string...I tend to abhor these dialogs, so don't use them often enough to know *every* quirk :)

Comment: This has absolutely no effect when user clicks on back button.